# "bzr uncommit" equivalent in Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs, bazaar

Bazaar has a wonderful `uncommit` command, which simply undoes the last commit.  Is there any equivalent in Mercurial?

**Edit**: Bazaar's uncommit command does not modify files – it removes the last commit and associated data (useful, for example, when you notice too late that there is a typo in a commit message or a file wasn't added that should have been).

For example:

```
$ bzr ci -m "Fixed a proooblem" <-- problem is misspelt
$ bzr uncommit
...
$ bzr ci -m "Fixed a problem" <-- Exactly as if the first commit was correct.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe `hg backout tip`?  I recommend http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/finding-and-fixing-mistakes.html for all details about `hg backout`, how it differs from `hg revert`, and many related topics, but if I undestand what `uncommit` does, it does seem exactly equivalent to `hg backout tip`.

Edit: in a comment you've now clarified you want to "delete history" -- that's hard (unless you're VERY fast on the draw, maybe;-)... per the red-bean book again:

> Since Mercurial treats history as accumulative—every change builds on top of all changes that preceded it—you generally can't just make disastrous changes disappear. The one exception is when you've just committed a change, and it hasn't been pushed or pulled into another repository. That's when you can safely use the hg rollback command

So if you just want to *try to* "make it disappear" (and you're lucky enough that it hasn't yet been pushed or pulled elsewhere), then `hg rollback` may be a better approach!

Comment: Close, but not quite.
`bzr revert` will leave all the files in place, ready to be re-committed.

Comment: anyway, "hg rollback" seems more and more like what you want -- it rolls back the latest _transaction_ (commit or pull), though, per red-bean book again, "you can only rollback once" and "it's useless once you've pushed".

Comment: Ah, yes – I was just reading about rollback when I thought I'd come back here to see if there were any more comments.
Rollback is *almost* what I want... But it doesn't put the files back for me (ie, a revert is required to put the files back where they were before the commit)... But I don't think I'll complain any more :)
Thanks for the help Alex!

Answer (score 23):

You want the [`hg rollback`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/Rollback) command, but see below if you're using Mercurial 2.2 or later.

The rollback command will remove the last **transaction** from your repository. A commit is a transaction, so you can use this as

```
% hg commit -m 'My elaburate bugfix.' foo.c foo.h
% hg rollback
% hg commit -m 'My elaborate bugfix.' foo.c foo.h
```

After the rollback the files will again be seen as modified, and this means that the second commit will store the same changes as the first, but with a better commit message.

**Beware:** `hg rollback` is more powerful than a simple "uncommit" function and you can use it to **throw away work** if you are not careful. To throw away a commit do

```
$ hg commit -m 'My big and very difficult bugfix'
$ hg pull --update
$ hg rollback
```

You've now lost the last commit you made and since you updated the working copy to some other revision, the changes in that commit are **gone**. So you should only use `hg rollback` to undo a commit if you're certain that `hg commit` really was the last command that operated on the working copy.

Also, if you have not given the commit message on the command line, then you cannot just press up-arrow twice to redo the commit after a rollback. However, Mercurial 1.5 and later will save your last commit message in `.hg/last-message.txt` so that you can always find it again after a rollback.

Mercurial 2.2 has a new **`--amend` flag** for `hg commit`. This let's you amend the last commit with new changes. It simply incorporates the changes listed by `hg status` into the parent commit, as if you had rolled back and committed again.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't "hg revert" do that?

Comment: It will revert the files, but I'd like the entire commit (message and all) stricken from the history.

Comment: Or maybe there isn't something `hg help revert` isn't showing me...?

Comment: "hg revert" does not change the history. Instead "hg revert" changes the working copy -- you use it to revert uncommited changes back to some earlier revision (typically the working copy parent revision). To redo a commit you cannot use "hg revert", I suggest "hg rollback" instead.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the comments, it seems that you want a way to simply do away with the record of the commit without undoing the changes to the file. In Mercurial, there is no automated way of doing this. `hg revert` is as close as you're going to get.

However, you *could* do this with a couple manual steps. When you invoke `hg revert`, its default behavior is to take the files in the changeset you are reverting and rename them as `filename.ext.orig`, where `ext` is the original extension of the file. The reverted versions then take on the original filename. So what you could do is run `hg revert`, delete the files with the original names, and remove `.orig` from the backup files' names. Then re-commit with your corrected log message. Just don't do this with any revision other than the tip because you'll probably get a lot of changed files and forget which ones belonged in which changeset.

I also would not recommend doing this if you've already pushed your changesets out to a remote repo. Only do this if everything is still only local.

Let me know if you need further explanation. I've had to do this on occasion, so I'm familiar with the process.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I think `hg rollback` is what I'm looking for.

Comment: From the hg command line help on rollback, "It will also restore the dirstate at the time of the last transaction." Isn't this what you're trying to avoid?

Comment: @Marc: no, he wants the dirstate back too. That is what keeps track of added files, for example. So "hg add foo.c; hg commit; hg rollback" will leave foo.c added as per "hg status".

Comment: By the way, I agree that talking about "the dirstate" is poor style since users shouldn't have to be aware of this terminology.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the "hg strip" command from the "mq" extension. It is almost exact equivalent of "bzr uncommit". Beware though, when you pushed your errant commit earlier to another repository, it will be recreated with the nearest pull from it.

Comment: Sorry, this is incorrect — `hg strip` will delete changesets from the repository while `bzr uncommit` will set the repository and working tree back to the state they were in immediately before the commit.

Comment: Well, that's exactly why i used the word 'almost' - the only difference seems to be the state of the working directory. I just thought that it is worth mentioning, as this is the only Mercurial equivalent for 'bzr uncommit' (and sadly, a non-obvious one, so it is hard to find), capable of removing multiple changesets NOT immediately after the commit. According to Bazaar docs, bzr uncommit can do that. If you know of another history-tampering Mercurial command capable of removing multiple changesets (like for example 'bzr uncommit -r 1'), then please let me know. I'd be happy to learn about it.